# Detect and display changes to webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to track a couple URLs for when they make changes, like add new articles, and for the script to be a continues running program that will print a message that something has changed, and if possible, what has changed. I originally have a script that calls the URL, makes a hash of the data, and x seconds later repeats the process and compares the hashes for changes, but I was getting a lot of false alerts anytime anything changed in the higher levels of the URL, not just the specific sub domain.

My question is, is there a way to have Beautiful soup perform something like this so I know when an article is added, or is there a way to modify my current script to only look at the subdomain for changes by utilizing something else besides a hash comparison.

My current script/attempt:

```
`# Importing libraries
import time
import hashlib
import logging
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# setting the URL you want to monitor
url = Request('Input URL here',
            headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

# to perform a GET request and load the
# content of the website and store it in a var
 response = urlopen(url).read()

# to create the initial hash
currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()
print("running")
time.sleep(10)
while True:
    try:
        # perform the get request and store it in a var
        response = urlopen(url).read()

        # create a hash
        currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()

        # wait for 30 seconds
        time.sleep(30)

        # perform the get request
        response = urlopen(url).read()

        # create a new hash
        newHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()

        # check if new hash is same as the previous hash
        if newHash == currentHash:
            continue

        # if something changed in the hashes
        else:
            # notify
            logging.info("something changed in given URL")

            # again read the website
            response = urlopen(url).read()

            # create a hash
            currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest()

            # wait for 30 seconds
            time.sleep(30)
            continue

    # To handle exceptions
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("error")`
```

My current script let off many false alerts due to changes in the higher level domains of the URL since I was comparing the hash of the subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have, I think, is not that there are changes at higher levels of the url, but that the pages you are looking at are constantly changing (for example adding timestamps, and very much more).

The way to resolve this is to look at which lines in a webpage have changed since you last looked. In this way you can take a note of which lines change regularly, and ignore them when looking for a significant change.

The code below looks at a webpage every second, and using difflib prints out a list of the numbers of the lines which have changed since the last look.

```
import difflib
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import time

link = "https://website/"

url = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
r_new = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
# print(r_new)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    r_old = r_new
    url = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    r_new = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

    diff = difflib.context_diff(r_new.splitlines(keepends=True),
                                r_old.splitlines(keepends=True), n=0)

    differences = []
    for line in diff:
        if (line.startswith('*** ') or line.startswith('--- ')) and len(line) > 5:
            differences.append(line.strip(' -*\n'))
    if not differences:
        differences = "No change"
    print(differences)
```

Here is a sample output:

```
['470', '470', '575', '575']
['470', '470', '575', '575']
['470', '470', '575', '575']
```

So in this case lines 470 and 575 change with every reading. If this was the page you were interested in, then all you would need to do is to look for a change in this list.

By the way, don't forget to check your site's robots.txt file to check its policy on web bots.

Caution: this code accesses the website every second in order to build a picture of changes over the first few seconds, and should only be run for a few cycles. Accessing a website this frequently could cause the site to bar you from further access.

Comment: @Ethan I think that this is a useful question, but that the title, which mentions Beautiful Soup, might give the wrong idea. I would propose that you change it to simply 'Detect and display changes to a webpage'. What do you think?